# Show all version of excel file in upload control (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, excel, upload

The code below is my code for upload control.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
```

its only will show Excel (.xlsx) files in upload control. How can I make it show Excel (.xls) files as well?

your comment is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `accept` property value can be set of comma separated strings.

```
<asp:FileUpload 
    ID="FileUpload1" 
    runat="server" accept="application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
```